# HP stream 13.3 producing noise

Tags: google-chrome

We made a fan for my son(5yrs). We connected the fan with a USB to the laptop. While connected 3 wires it was moving. But when we connected the 4th wire(2 and 2 wires are separated), the laptop turned off. Now, it is producing sounds. Please suggest me what's the problem? If possible the solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Images would help of what you built.

But from your description you used 4 wires in total, when powering a fan you only need +ve and -ve which are the outer two terminals.

The other (middle) two terminals are for data - if you have a fan with a built-in speed controller app then those middle connections would have been necessary.

Definitely remove that usb connection and try re-starting : if it does not then you may have a serious problem.
Do you have a current back-up?

Comment: Most fan speed adjustors just use potentiometers and still don't need to use the data lines.